# Template Function Branch Optimization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, directx

I'm trying to write a template method to create shaders for Direct3D. The API functions to create each type of shader as well as the types of shaders have different names. So, I wrote the following code:

```
class Shader final
{
public:
    explicit Shader( _In_ ID3DBlob *const pBlob );

    template <class T>
    void Create
        ( std::weak_ptr<ID3D11Device>& pDevice
        , CComPtr<T>& pResource )
    {
        auto p_Device = pDevice.lock();

        if ( mp_Blob && p_Device )
        {
            HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
            ID3D11ClassLinkage* pClassLinkage = nullptr; // unsupported for now
            pResource.Release();
            CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceChild> pRes;
            if ( std::is_same<T, ID3D11VertexShader>() )
            {
                hr = p_Device->CreateVertexShader
                    ( mp_Blob->GetBufferPointer()
                    , mp_Blob->GetBufferSize()
                    , pClassLinkage
                    , reinterpret_cast<ID3D11VertexShader**>( &pRes ) );
            }
            else if ( std::is_same<T, ID3D11HullShader>() )
            {
                hr = p_Device->CreateHullShader
                    ( mp_Blob->GetBufferPointer()
                    , mp_Blob->GetBufferSize()
                    , pClassLinkage
                    , reinterpret_cast<ID3D11HullShader**>( &pRes ) );
            }
            else if ( std::is_same<T, ID3D11DomainShader>() )
            {
                hr = p_Device->CreateDomainShader
                    ( mp_Blob->GetBufferPointer()
                    , mp_Blob->GetBufferSize()
                    , pClassLinkage
                    , reinterpret_cast<ID3D11DomainShader**>( &pRes ) );
            }
            else if ( std::is_same<T, ID3D11GeometryShader>() )
            {
                hr = p_Device->CreateGeometryShader
                    ( mp_Blob->GetBufferPointer()
                    , mp_Blob->GetBufferSize()
                    , pClassLinkage
                    , reinterpret_cast<ID3D11GeometryShader**>( &pRes ) );
            }
            else if ( std::is_same<T, ID3D11ComputeShader>() )
            {
                hr = p_Device->CreateComputeShader
                    ( mp_Blob->GetBufferPointer()
                    , mp_Blob->GetBufferSize()
                    , pClassLinkage
                    , reinterpret_cast<ID3D11ComputeShader**>( &pRes ) );
            }
            else if ( std::is_same<T, ID3D11PixelShader>() )
            {
                hr = p_Device->CreatePixelShader
                    ( mp_Blob->GetBufferPointer()
                    , mp_Blob->GetBufferSize()
                    , pClassLinkage
                    , reinterpret_cast<ID3D11PixelShader**>( &pRes ) );
            }
            else
            {
                assert( false
                    && "Need a pointer to an ID3D11 shader interface" );
            }
            //TODO: log hr's error code.
            assert( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && "Error: shader creation failed!" );
            if ( FAILED( hr ) )
            {
                pResource.Release();
            }
            else
            {
                hr = pRes->QueryInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS( &pResource ) );
                assert( SUCCEEDED( hr ) );
            }
        }
    }
private:
    CComPtr<ID3DBlob> mp_Blob;
};
```

It should work, although I have not tested it yet. But the issue is that the compiler doesn't throw away the branching paths that will certainly not be taken. So for example:

```
CComPtr<ID3D11DomainShader> pDS;
//pShader is an instance of Shader class
pShader->Create(pDevice, pDs);
```

will create a domain shader. But the compiler keeps all the paths in the generated function instead of generating just

```
void Create
        ( std::weak_ptr<ID3D11Device>& pDevice
        , CComPtr<ID3D11DomainShader>& pResource )
    {
        auto p_Device = pDevice.lock();

        if ( mp_Blob && p_Device )
        {
            HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
            ID3D11ClassLinkage* pClassLinkage = nullptr; // unsupported for now
            pResource.Release();
            CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceChild> pRes;
            if ( true ) // this is the evaluation of std::is_same<ID3D11DomainShader, ID3D11DomainShader>()
            {
                hr = p_Device->CreateDomainShader
                    ( mp_Blob->GetBufferPointer()
                    , mp_Blob->GetBufferSize()
                    , pClassLinkage
                    , reinterpret_cast<ID3D11DomainShader**>( &pRes ) );
            }
            
            //TODO: log hr's error code.
            assert( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && "Error: shader creation failed!" );
            if ( FAILED( hr ) )
            {
                pResource.Release();
            }
            else
            {
                hr = pRes->QueryInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS( &pResource ) );
                assert( SUCCEEDED( hr ) );
            }
        }
    }
```

I think there should be a way to do this because the type of the shader is known at compile-time, but I don't really know how (my metaprogramming skills need yet to grow).

## p.s.

I compiled both in `debug` and `releas` setting and in both the paths are kept.

Comment: a) You have optimizations enabled? b) Have you tried using `::value` instead of `()` to access the value from `std::is_same`?

Comment: Yes, I enabled optimization, but that doesn't seem to help. Haven't tried the `::value` option yet. Didn't know of it's existence.

Comment: Ok, just tried the `::value` thing, and didn't work (at least not without the `reinterpret_cast` casts.

Comment: You may just have overload instead of template method.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`?? That should not be necessary. You did remove the `()`, right? To be precise: `if( std::is_same<T, ID3D11VertexShader>::value ) { ...` - that *should* work. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @dogjones if it doesn't optimise this, Microsoft's one.

Comment: I've added an answer that tells you how to get what you want (functions that don't contain the code for each type) but I do advise you to use the high-performance (I use it in production code) pattern. You can have too much abstraction.

Comment: Why do you think the other branches are being kept?  How do you know?  Dissassembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following may help:

```
HRESULT createShader(
    ID3D11Device& pDevice,
    CComPtr<ID3D11VertexShader>& pResource,
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceChild> pRes)
{
    return p_Device.CreateVertexShader(
        mp_Blob->GetBufferPointer(),
        mp_Blob->GetBufferSize(),
        pClassLinkage,
        reinterpret_cast<ID3D11VertexShader**>(&pRes));
}
// similar for other Shader type

template <class T>
void Create(
    std::weak_ptr<ID3D11Device>& pDevice,
    CComPtr<T>& pResource)
{
    auto p_Device = pDevice.lock();

    if (!mp_Blob || !p_Device) {
        return;
    }
    pResource.Release();
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceChild> pRes;

    // ---------------- 8< --------------------
    // Here is the change: no more `if` to check type,
    // let the compiler choose the correct overload
    HRESULT hr = createShader(*p_device, pResource, pRes);
    // ---------------- >8 --------------------

    assert( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && "Error: shader creation failed!" );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) ) {
        pResource.Release();
    } else {
        hr = pRes->QueryInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS( &pResource ) );
        assert( SUCCEEDED( hr ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for proper application of the [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: Great rewrite, +1. However I need to stress that the original code is also fine performance wise, it's guaranteed by the standard to compile-time evaluate the is_same()s.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your optimisations:
I think you're upset about the code being created to handle everything regardless of which template type. 
You need to shift your `is_same` logic to the `enable_if` in my meta-programming solution, then the function that matches the template for what you want will ONLY be the code you want.

HOWEVER I interpret your question still as a problem of too much abstraction, you cannot use an `Animal` class to only accept a `Banana` if the underlying animal is a monkey.

(In this classic example, `Monkey` derives from `Animal` and `Banana` from `Food`, where `Animal` has a method `void eat(Food)`)

**Answer of how to do what you want well**

A bit long, so I skimmed it.

Remember meta-programming wont always save the day (there are many cases where you know the types but the program doesn't, take for example columns in database result sets).

**High performance**
Don't let unknown types in in the first place. Here's a common pattern:

```
class unverified_thing: public base_class {
public:
    unverified_thing(base_class* data): data(data) { type_code = -1; }
    void set_type_code(int to) { /*throw if not -1*/ type_code = to; }
    derived_A* get_as_derived_A() const { /*throw if not the right type code*/
        return *(derived_A*)data;
    }
    derived_B* get_as_derived_B() const { /*throw is not right type code*/
        return *(derived_B*)data;
    }
    //now do the base class methods
    whatever base_class_method() {
        return data->base_class_method();
    }
private:
    int type_code;
    base_class data;
};
```

Now you can pretend `unverified_thing` is your data, and you have introduced a form of type checking. You can afford to throw in the getter because you wont be calling that every frame or whatever. You only deal with that when you're setting up.

So say `shader` is the base class of `fragment_shader` and `vertex_shader`, you can be dealing with a `shader` but have set the type_id, so you can deal with `shader`s right until you compile your shader, then you can cast to the correct derived type with a runtime error if wrong. This avoids C++ RTTI which can be quite heavy.

Remember you can afford setup time, you want to make sure every bit of data you send into the engine is correct.

This type pattern comes from validated input only being allowed through (which stops SO many bugs) you have a `unverified_thing` that doesn't derive from the data type, you can only extract the data without error if you set the type to verified.

An even better way to do this (but can get messy quick) is to have:

```
template<bool VERIFIED=true>
class user_input {  };


/*somewhere in your dialog class (or whatever)*/
user_input<false> get_user_input() const { /*whatever*/ }

/*then have somewhere*/
user_input verify_input(const user_input<false>& some_input) { /*which will throw as needed*/ }
```

For large data classes of user_input it can be good to hide a `large_data*` inside the `user_input` class, but you get the idea.

**To use metaprogramming** (Limits how flexible the end result can be re. user input)

```
template<class U>
typename ::std::enable_if<my_funky_criteria<U>::value,funky_shader>::type
Create(::std::istream& input) { /*blah*/ }
```

with

```
template<class U>
struct my_funky_criteria: typename ::std::conditional</*what you want*/,::std::true_type,::std::false_type>::type { };
```

Comment: Thanks Alec. It sounds handy, but it'll take some time for me to translate this into code.

Comment: @rashmatash it's good you worry about EVERY cycle, the best thing you can do is make sure everything you give to the engine (I'm guessing that's what you're going for) is checked BEFORE entering, make anything unchecked look ugly. Also remember that templates are COMPILE TIME, so if you have any input (files and such) you'll have to write a lot of if statements to use the templated versions

Comment: you're absolutely right! I actually wrote resource loader that kinda checks every aspect of each resource to validate it before submitting it to the engine. It took me about 4k lines of validation code just for the different types of Direct3D resources. Indeed I didn't care much for the efficiency. The question I posted was a recurring problem that caused a lot of code duplication. That's why I decided to ask for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This *must* be a compiler setting issue, even though you stated that you use release mode. Have you checked that you're using /O3 and not /O2 in your release mode configuration? O2 optimizes for size and could perhaps reuse the same binary instead of creating a version for each type (even though I'm not sure if it's prohibited by the standard).

Also, check the disassembler window to see if the IDE simply cheats you. And rebuild your project, etc. Some times Visual Studio fails seeing changed header files.

There is simply no other answer than build settings in this particular case...